# ArcGIS interactive KML layer

Tags: javascript, kml, arcgis

I am working on an ArcGIS map. I need to be able to interact with KML layers.

Here is a minimal version of my current code:

```
map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "topo",
  center: [-108.663, 42.68],
  zoom: 6
});
parser.parse();

var kmlUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2142726/esrijs-samples/Wyoming.kml";
var kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl);
map.addLayer(kml);
kml.on("load", function() {
  console.log("done");
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/vtB24sZbZGaeHCEsU1ch?p=preview)

I'm looking to achieve something more like [this map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/fl_hover/), which outlines the layer on hover. (This example is from the [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) class, but my KML is dynamically generated. Is it possible to create a featurelayer dynamically from KML data?)

How can I listen for mouseover on a KML shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
var kmlUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2142726/esrijs-samples/Wyoming.kml";
var kml = new KMLLayer(kmlUrl);
map.addLayer(kml);
kml.on("load", function() {
  var layers = kml.getLayers()  
  layers[0].on("mouse-over", function () {
            alert("test");
        });
});
```

Turns out the KML layer is actually composed of FeatureLayers. The solution is to get the Feature Layers from the KMLLayer wi the `getLayers()` method.